# In gatling, how do I validate the value of a string extracted via the css check?

Tags: css, scala, gatling

I'm writing a Gatling simulation, and I want to verify both that a certain element exists, and that the content of one of its attributes starts with a certain substring. E.g.:

```
val scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("BasicSimulation")
  .exec(http("request_1")
  .get("/path/to/resource")
  .check(
    status.is(200),
    css("form#name", "action").ofType[String].startsWith(BASE_URL).saveAs("next_url")))
```

Now, when I add the `startsWith` above, the compiler reports an error that says `startsWith is not a member of io.gatling.http.check.body.HttpBodyCssCheckBuilder[String]`. If I leave the `startsWith` out, then everything works just fine. I know that the expected form element is *there*, but I cant confirm that its `@action` attribute starts with the correct base.

How can I confirm that the attribute start with a certain substring?

Answer (score 1):

Refer this https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/scenario/

I have copied the below from there but it is a session function and will work like below :-

```
doIf(session => session("myKey").as[String].startsWith("admin")) {  // executed if the session value stored in "myKey" starts with "admin"  exec(http("if true").get("..."))}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. I guess one option is to use a validator, but I'm not sure how if you can declare one on the fly to validate against your `BASE_URL` (the documentation doesn't really give any examples). You can use `transform` and `is`.

Could look like this:

```
css("form#name", "action").transform(_.startsWith(BASE_URL)).is(true)
```

If you also want to include the `saveAs` call in one go you could probably also do something like this:

```
css("form#name", "action").transform(_.substring(0, BASE_URL.length)).is(BASE_URL).saveAs
```

But that's harder to read. Also I'm not sure what happens when substring throws an exception (like IndexOutOfBounds).